# How to upload any file to s3 bucket with angular 4

Tags: angular, file-upload, amazon-s3

Is there any specific way to upload files to s3 bucket with angular 4. I found few solution like [file upload to s3 with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322697/upload-file-from-angularjs-directly-to-amazon-s3-using-signed-url), but the npm package does not exist. is there any other easy way with angular 4. hope your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 imgattached(img) {
    AWS.config.region = 'Enter your region'; // 1. Enter your region
    var bucketName = 'Enter your bucket name'; // Enter your bucket name
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'your identity pool' // 2. Enter your identity pool
    });

    var that = this;
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({
      params: {
        Bucket: bucketName
      }
    });
    var a = img.target.files;
    var file = a[0];

        console.log(file.name);
        if (file) {
          var objKey = file.name;
          var params = {
            Key: objKey,
            ContentType: file.type,
            Body: file,
            ACL: 'public-read'
          };

          bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            if (data) {
            console.log(data.Location);//done
            }
          });
        }

  }
```

/////////////////Html////////////////////